# How to ssh between two ec2 instance with ssh keys?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have two EC2 instances:

Serve 1, OS: Centos -  7.5
Serve 2, OS: Centos -  7.5
Default username: centos

Both are configured for passwordless login, so I have the ssh key with me.

I am able to ssh to both servers using the ssh key from my host.

But when I am trying to ssh from Server 1 to Server 2, it's failing.

I found out that the private keys are under /etc/ssh

```
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys   1679 Oct  7 14:42 ssh_host_rsa_key
```

Error

```
sudo ssh -i ./ssh_host_rsa_key centos@172.26.7.177
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

So where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this would be to create a new key for the user you want on the Server1 to be connecting to Server2, using ssh-keygen, and copying that user's PUBLIC key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of Server2, then repeating the same procedure for the reverse trip.

YOUR private key must remain yours, it must never leave your PC, don't use it by copying it on the servers, I can assure you that you're not simplifying anything by doing that.

In all my CentOS 7 servers the default SSH configuration resides in ~/.ssh, the private key is usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and the public is usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
these are the only 3 files you should need to create or edit for every machine:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

ensure that the ~/.ssh directory is chmod'ed 700 and the files inside 600.

You can use `ssh-copy-id` to send the public key from one server to another once you have created both sets of keys.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new user and used ssh-copy-id, and it worked. Do you know where is pvt key for the default user, ~/.ssh Folder is empty at the beginning

Comment: At the beginning, ~/.ssh is correctly empty, using ssh-keygen you create both a private and a public key, at the same time.
Keep in mind that you can recreate the public key from the private key, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confusing the keys.

SSH authentication uses asymmetric crypto aka public key crypto. So every key consists of two parts, a *private key* (the one that must be kept secret) and a *public key* which is shared with the other party.

The private keys in `/etc/ssh` on the **server** are the ones for proving to the client that it is connecting to the right server.

The private keys for logging in are stored on the **client** normally in `/home/user/.ssh/`

Is there a particular reason why you want to ssh from one instance to the other? From a security perspective it is not a great idea.

**Debugging ssh**:
For debugging ssh just use `ssh -vv` and add more `v` according to taste.

Comment: sudo ssh -i ./id_rsa centos@172.26.7.177
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: I moved to the .ssh/ but I am stilling getting the error, I am trying to configure password less login for ansible.

Comment: But you copied the keys from your local machine to the instance from which you are trying to connect?

Comment: I compared the keys, which I have in PC, and the host, I found the keys which match is under /etc/ssh/, that is the same key which I am using for ssh from host1 to host2

Comment: How do you know they "match"?

Comment: compare both the key, they have the same characters.

Comment: HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' -- from /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: @Hulk711 Okay, I'm not sure what's going on. I have added some more info to my answer and your keys should definitely NOT be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier for you to create a new key for user centos in Server_A:

$ ssh-keygen

Once created, copy your /home/centos/.ssh/id_rsa.pub content to /home/centos/.ssh/authorized_keys on Server_B

Once completed, you can ssh in to Server_B from Server_A without a password.